# are index page reads tracked in mysql 5.5 performance_schema tables?

Tags: mysql

My question is about mysql's internal tracking of index usage.
I wish to know if particular indexes are being used. In other DBMSs there are infrastructure tables that track page_reads and page_hits for objects like tables and indexes.  I see in the file_summary_by_instance table that table file names are tracked along with the count of reads and the total bytes read.  Do we have anything like that that tracks indexes?

Answer (score 0):

The performance schema instruments table I/O,
and keep statistics per indexes, starting with MySQL 5.6.

See table `performance_schema.table_io_waits_summary_by_index_usage`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/table-waits-summary-tables.html#table-io-waits-summary-by-index-usage-table

This is not available in MySQL 5.5.